# How can I add items to a DataGridView and sort them automatically after input?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have the following fragment of code:

```
                    int rowID = dgTrackIDStatus.Rows.Add();
                    DataGridViewRow row = dgTrackIDStatus.Rows[rowID];
                    switch (reg)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            status = "Received";
                            statusDB = "RECEIVED";
                            SaveTrackIDORWIP(TrackID, statusDB);
                            lbOkQty.Text = OKObjects(TrackID).ToString();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            color = Color.Red;
                            foreColor = Color.Blue;
                            statusDB = "PENDING";
                            status = "Pending - Material Shortage";
                            SaveTrackIDORWIP(TrackID, statusDB);
                            break;
                    }

                    row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = (Color)color;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = TrackID;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = status;
                    row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = (Color)foreColor;
```

It will add the rows containing data according to queries, so, for example, with the input of 7 values:
[image: 7 inputs]

I want to be able to reverse the displaying of the rows, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a DataTable and bind the DataTable to the DataGridView. Adding, removing, sorting etc records to the Datatable can be reflected in the DataGridView.